# Paper accepted in journal, should I remove style file for arXiv preprint?

Tags: publications, arxiv

I recently sent a paper to a journal (which I put on arXiv beforehand) which has now been accepted with some corrections. I want to put the corrected version on arXiv. The corrected version is written using the style file supplied by the journal.

Should I remove this style file? Does it matter if I don't? Will the journal get mad?

Comment: For physics journals, at least as of 5 years ago, they didn't want you to post the version using their style sheet on arXiv. That may have changed by now.

Comment: @MarkFischler: Indeed they have (see my answer) and I am rather sure that this was already the case five years ago.

Comment: Does the style file contain a license?  This may contain the answer to your question.

Comment: thanks for the comments. The style file has a copyright but I can't see a license. Anyway, I think it is better for me to remove the style file so I have consistency in my arXiv preprints.

Comment: @math_guy Reformatting takes time; spend the time more productively, do research instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Legally**, the style file at first only is the software which you use to *generate* your paper and thus there should not be any problems in most cases, for the same reasons that you do not need to ask Microsoft for permission each time you publish something generated with Word. I see three problem cases, however:

- If you use TeX, and ArXiv does not have the style file and thus you need to supply it, which would make it be published alongside your article. In this case you may be distributing a software that you are not allowed not distribute. In my experience, many style files are free to distribute though; have a look at it whether it contains some license.
- The style file includes a logo or similar (e.g., Royal Society Publishing’s style file does this), which in turn may not have a license that allows you to distribute it and also probably is a problem because of the next point.
- The style file makes your paper mention the journal’s name, publisher, or similar, which creates the false impression that your preprint is actually a publication of that journal.

**Will the journal get mad?** – Of course you need to regard the journal’s copyright agreement (which you accepted) with respect to publishing preprints in general or on ArXiv in specific ([Sherpa Romeo](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/) is a database that helps you to find this out). But if the journal allows you to publish a preprint content-wise, I do not see any reasons why using its style file would enrage it, given that the above problem cases do not apply. Some journals even allow you publishing the journal’s version of the paper on ArXiv, e.g., the [Physical Review series](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/issn/1539-3755/).

Finally, a **stylistical** argument: If the journal has a single-column layout but your paper has no long equations or something else that would make such a format a good idea, you may want to opt for a two-column layout for your preprint.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer. So it seems I am allowed to post post-review preprints. Upon consideration I think removing the style file is better so I have some consistency across my arXiv preprints.

Comment: I believe some journal style files have a "preprint" option you can toggle.

Answer (score 2):

I think what matters in most cases is whether the journal staff (i.e., not just the external peer reviewers) made some corrections and improvements to the paper. If they did, you generally can't post the fruit of their labor on arXiv without violating the journal's rights. But you can post a version without those corrections and improvements -- and then you can even add additional other improvements of your own that were not in the journal's published version.